# Use href NOT onClick in hyperlink - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

I have the following HTML that pops up a window when I click the 'Open Sesame' link:

`<a href="/about-us/" title="Find out About Us" onclick="javascript:void window.open('/about-us/','1329304840803','width=1050,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Open Sesame</a></li>`

However, I was wondering **is it possible I could remove the 'onClick' part and just have the javascript within the href** & still get the same new window effect. **Is this possible?**

Many thanks for any pointers

Comment: I bet trying it would have been faster...

Comment: Good call, Dimitri. Much faster. I just assumed I *needed* the onClick.

Comment: Rule of thumb i use: Never assume anything :)

Comment: Hehe, I assumed you would say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
<a href="javascript:void window.open('/about-us/','1329304840803','width=1050,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');" title="Find out About Us">Open Sesame</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/NqfMX/

---

However, I would recommend an event listener for this. It makes your HTML code much tidier and seperates the function from the HTML design:

```
<a class="opensesame" href="/about-us/" title="Find out About Us">Open Sesame</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​$(function(){
    $("a.opensesame").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('/about-us/','1329304840803','width=1050,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/NqfMX/1/

Comment: Many thanks, Curt. I'm off now with my offline tail between my legs.

Comment: Hey Curt. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with IE. I'm using IE9. Any ideas why not?

Comment: @mcgarriers Hi, I'm running IE 9.0.8112 and both of my fiddles work fine on that.

Comment: Thanks, Curt. I will try again in a minute & see how I get on :) Back in a minute...

Comment: JsFiddle appears to be having a "moment"... :)

Comment: Green Tick says "Yes!!" :-) Thanks again, Curt. Both I & JsF were having "moments" there. Thanks for your patience throughout. Have a great day.

Comment: @mcgarriers Not a problem, glad to help :)